# Looking to get a single observation output

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions, presto, trino

Looking for some assistance as I'm getting two observation in the output and I'm expecting one, think its due to the multiple repeating date stamps.

```
id did  rid date_pulled             s created_at              date                    time          
1  123  123 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 1 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 2021-03-19 00:09:36.199 2023-04-11 07:48:18.692 
1  123  123 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 1 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 2021-03-19 00:09:36.199 2023-04-19 02:26:26.836
2  123  123 2020-05-07 20:50:49.818 2 2020-05-07 20:50:49.818 2021-03-19 00:09:36.199 2023-04-19 02:26:26.836
1  123  123 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 1 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 2021-03-19 00:09:36.199 2023-04-21 11:54:11.132
2  123  123 2020-05-07 20:50:49.818 2 2020-05-07 20:50:49.818 2021-03-19 00:09:36.199 2023-04-21 11:54:11.132
```

I'm expecting a single observation output with the following 3 columns, could not squeeze score column into the example data above.  Working code below.

```
select  date_pulled, score, did
from (
    select *,  max(time) over (partition by did) max_time
    from grs_datalake_prod_distill_lexis_nexis_db.credit_report_detail
)
where max_time = time
```

Comment: It is unclear which result you want, and what is *an observation*. Sample data, current and desired results, as three separated tables, would probably help us help you.

Comment: Basically: when there are multiple observations that have the latest date, which one(s) do you want to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will add `time` to select you will see that you have two rows with the same `time`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(id, did, rid, date_pulled, s, created_at, date, time)     AS (
    values (1, 123, 123, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', 1, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', '2021-03-19 00:09:36.199', '2023-04-11 07:48:18.692'),
        (1, 123, 123, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', 1, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', '2021-03-19 00:09:36.199', '2023-04-19 02:26:26.836'),
        (2, 123, 123, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.818', 2, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.818', '2021-03-19 00:09:36.199', '2023-04-19 02:26:26.836'),
        (1, 123, 123, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', 1, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.155', '2021-03-19 00:09:36.199', '2023-04-21 11:54:11.132'),
        (2, 123, 123, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.818', 2, '2020-05-07 20:50:49.818', '2021-03-19 00:09:36.199', '2023-04-21 11:54:11.132')
)

-- query
select  date_pulled, s, did, time
from (
    select *,  max(time) over (partition by did) max_time
    from dataset
)
where max_time = time;
```

Output:

| date_pulled | s | did | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 | 1 | 123 | 2023-04-21 11:54:11.132 |
| 2020-05-07 20:50:49.818 | 2 | 123 | 2023-04-21 11:54:11.132 |

So you need some kind of tie-breaker here. You can use "random" (not truly random of course) following the `row_number` approach:

```sql
select  date_pulled, s, did, time
from (
    select *,
        -- can add extra sorting
        -- like date_pulled desc to order by 
        -- to serve as tiebreaker
        row_number() over (partition by did order by time desc) rn -- order by time desc, date_pulled desc
    from dataset
)
where rn = 1;
```

Output:

| date_pulled | s | did | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 | 1 | 123 | 2023-04-21 11:54:11.132 |

Or similar using `group by` + `max_by`:

```sql
select  did, max_by(date_pulled, time) date_pulled, max_by(s, time) s 
from dataset
group by did;
```

| did | date_pulled | s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-05-07 20:50:49.155 | 1 |

Comment: TY for the well thought out explanation